# Mockito problems and says undefinied type while ı am testing my service

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mocking, mockito

I am writing unit test but I am facing an error some how. I am triyng to test my ServiceImpl just showing my entire code down below My code below;

My Service Class

```
@Service
public class PlaneServiceImpl implements PlaneCallerService {

    private final PlaneFactory planeFactory;

    public PlaneServiceImpl(PlaneFactory planeFactory) {
        this.planeFactory = planeFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPlaneType(String planeType) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append(planeFactory.getPlane(planeType).getType());
        stringBuilder.append(" Plane has produced.");

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Plane  class down below

```
public interface Plane {

    String getType();
}
```

My PlaneFactory class down below;

```
@Component
public class PlaneFactory {

public Plane getPlane(String planeType) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(planeType)) {
        throw new PlaneTypeNotFoundException();
    }

    if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("lightJet")) {
        return new LightJet();

    } else if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("midJet")) {
        return new MidJet();
```

My Mock Test just down below

```
public class PlaneCallerServiceImplTest {

    private PlaneFactory planeFactory;
    private PlaneCallerService planeCallerService;
    private plane plane;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        planeFactory = mock(PlaneFactory.class);
        planeCallerService = new PlaneCallerServiceImpl(planeFactory);
        plane= mock(Plane.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void testPlaneType() {

        String planeType = "";

        when(planeFactory.getPlane(planeType)).thenReturn(plane);

        String result = planeCallerService.getplaneType(planeType);

        assertNotNull(result);

    }
}
```

I'm getting `The method getPlane(String) is undefined for the type PlaneFactory`

I am quite new for unit test and also mock test any help would be appreciate
Thank you in advanced

Comment: What's the error that is being thrown?

Comment: The method getPlane(String) is undefined for the type PlaneFactory

Comment: I would recommend cleaning and rebuilding everything.  I suspect you've got an earlier version of `PlaneFactory.class` lying round somewhere that it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that from the below statement:

```
when(planeFactory.getPlane(planeType)).thenReturn(plane);
```

you are returning a mocked response of type `Plane` but in that mocked response when you call `Plane.getType()` that method is not implemented.

You can mock the response of that too, add

```
when(plane.getType()).thenReturn("SOME_MOCKED_STRING");
```

This should start to work.

Below is the complete test class:

```
public class PlaneServiceImplTest {

    private PlaneFactory planeFactory;
    private PlaneServiceImpl planeCallerService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        planeFactory = mock(PlaneFactory.class);
        planeCallerService = new PlaneServiceImpl(planeFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPlaneType() {
        Plane plane = mock(Plane.class);
        when(planeFactory.getPlane(anyString())).thenReturn(plane);
        
        String result = planeCallerService.getPlaneType("Test");

        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Test
 public void testPlaneType() {

  String planeType = "";

  when(plane.getType()).thenReturn(planeType);

  String result = planeCallerService.getCarType(planeType);

  assertNotNull(result);        Nosuch method error ı am receiving

Comment: @johnmohn I've edited my answer. It should be working now

Comment: when(planeFactory.getPlane(anyString())).thenReturn(plane);

Comment: @johnmohn the issue is with `planeFactory` variable, ensure you have the line: `planeFactory = mock(PlaneFactory.class);` in your `@Before`. You can also add it in your TestMethod

Comment: @Before
    public void setUp() {

        planeFactory = mock(PlaneFactory.class);
        planeCallerService = new PlaneServiceImpl(planeFactory);
    }  yes it is there

Comment: @johnmohn can you move it to the TestMethod and check if it gets resolved? By putting a breakpoint, does `@Before` get triggered?

Comment: planeFactory comes null

Comment: @johnmohn I've created a Github repository of the code, maybe you can refer that Link: https://github.com/ImCarrot/SampleTest

Comment: thank you it worked you are a life saver :) when ı use anystring   what can ı put instead of anystring()

Comment: @johnmohn glad I could help, you can pass in a sample string instead of `anyString()`. But note that, if you're using a specific string then the mock response would only be returned when that exact string is passed

Comment: do ı need to write those with junit or mock ı think I will go on with junit can you also provide me how to write test with scenario                            @Component
public class PlaneFactory {

public Plane getPlane(String planeType) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(planeType)) {
        throw new PlaneTypeNotFoundException();
    }

    if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("lightJet")) {
        return new LightJet();

    } else if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("midJet")) {
        return new MidJet();

Comment: if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("lightJet")) {
        return new LightJet();

Comment: @johnmohn are you still struggling with the Test Cases for PlaneFactory? Sorry for the delayed response, I was away for sometime